# How do i fix this : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'TeamID'

Tags: entity-framework, entity-relationship, entity-framework-migrations

```
public class Team
    {
        public Team()
        {
            TeamSchemes = new HashSet<Scheme>();
            TeamUsers = new HashSet<PLUser>();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Office")]
        public int OfficeID { get; set;}
        public virtual Office Office { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("TeamLeader")]
        public int TeamLeaderID { get; set; }


        public virtual PLUser TeamLeader { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Scheme> TeamSchemes { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PLUser> TeamUsers {get;set;}


    }
```

I have a team object and a user object.

The relationships i want are:
A Team has a TeamLeader (User)
A Team has many Users which can be in that team

here is what i have in my User object for these relationships

```
        [ForeignKey("Team")]
        public int? TeamID { get; set; }
        public virtual Team Team { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Team> TeamsLeading { get; set; }
```

however when running codeFirst migrations i was getting an extra column called Team_ID from somewhere

i explicitly stated my relationships in modelbuilder like so:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Team>().HasRequired(x => x.TeamLeader).WithMany(u=>u.TeamsLeading).HasForeignKey(t=>t.TeamLeaderID);

modelBuilder.Entity<PLUser>().HasOptional(x => x.Team).WithMany(t=>t.TeamUsers).HasForeignKey(x => x.TeamID);

modelBuilder.Entity<PLUser>().HasMany(u => u.TeamsLeading).WithRequired(t => t.TeamLeader);
```

The migration code ran succesfully and seem to show the intended outcome. However when i run the application i get the following error and the app won't run:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'TeamID'.

Any help on the model relationship / fixing issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in your comment that EF can't determine the relationships. One way to do it with annotations is with [InverseProperty](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-entity-framework/9781449317867/ch04s03.html). Try:

```
[InverseProperty("Team")]
public virtual ICollection<PLUser> TeamUsers {get;set;}
```

and

```
[InverseProperty("TeamLeader")]
public virtual ICollection<Team> TeamsLeading { get; set; }
```

EDIT: You may have to play with it (been a while since I did it), but you may want to go something like this:

```
[InverseProperty("TeamsLeading")]
public virtual PLUser TeamLeader { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Scheme> TeamSchemes { get; set; }
[InverseProperty("Team")]
public virtual ICollection<PLUser> TeamUsers {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The persistent attribute **ForeignKey** usage is wrong here. You are applying it to the primitive value itself.
The correct usage is to apply it to navigation properties, to indicate what primitive property stores its FK value.

In your case it is not required because EF will resolve it by convention:

```
public class PLUser{        
    public int? TeamID { get; set; }
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
}
```

When EF finds Team navigation property, it will try to find within PLUser a primitive property named TeamID or TeamId,  with the same type as the Team class PK, to use it as ForeignKey.

Comment: unfortunately this hasn't solved the issue. I think it's to do with the fact there are two relationships between Users and Team

1) User has optional TeamID
2) Team has Collection of TeamUsers (based on relationship 1)
3) Team has a TeamLeaderID refers to ID of User (seperate relationship

Comment: I don't see nothing exceptional with those relationships, that why EF was made for ;). Did you clean up your code from those ForeignKey attributes?